# update/insert access database using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it possible in python by which I can write a simple `.py` script to update my access database records or insert new one if any i have on behalf of me? new records are to be pulled from Excel and pushed to be in the database.

***MS-Access2010*** i am using.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible. You'll probably want to do it with the [`comtypes` module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/comtypes), which allows communication between Windows processes using the Component Object Model (COM).

[Here's an example of a script that does that posted in another question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094537/how-do-you-create-a-mdb-database-file-in-python)

Getting the information out of Microsoft Excel can be done with a lot of modules, but one I've had success with is [`openpyxl`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl/1.6.1). Some examples of reading Excel workbooks with it can be found [here](http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/usage.html).

Comment: Shall i need to install using `easy_install comtypes` or it is in `stdlib`?

Comment: Neither of them are stdlib, you should install them using `pip` and a `virtualenv` if you prefer.

Comment: `openpyxl` i have installed already! now i need the one `comptypes`. but any documentation of that module you would like to share please?